# Adding the same column to several data frames by looping

Tags: r

I have four data frames, each one consisting of 61 rows and 5 columns. They are called "London", "Chicago", "Frankfurt" and "Melbourne".

Now I want to replace the first column by the values from 1:61. This is what I tried and what did not work:

```
q <- 1:61

for (i in c("London", "Chicago", "Frankfurt", "Melbourne")) {
   get(i)[1] <- q
}
```

Does anybody have a solution which includes keeping the data frames and avoids working with lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a list:

```
#Value
q <- 61
#Objects
cities <- c("London", "Chicago", "Frankfurt", "Melbourne")
#List
List <- mget(ls()[grepl(paste0(cities,collapse = '|'),ls())])
#Loop
for (i in 1:length(List)) {
  List[[i]][,1] <- q
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
This works, but I need to keep the data frames for the further processing and therefore try to avoid working with lists in this case.

Comment: @climdrag If you want to recover the dataframes you can use `list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)` hope that helps!

Comment: The last advice was very useful. It did the job perfectly now, thanks!